Struggling with input and output differences in shapes for Convolutional Autoencoders
When fitting my model i get the following error:
ValueError: Input 0 of layer "sequential_15" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 27088, 64, 1), found shape=(None, 27086, 64, 1)
I think MaxPool2D is floor rounding while UpSamling2D is Ceiling Rounding. When i look at the model summary, im seeing that the floor rounding is resulting into a different input and output shape, however, im struggling to find the necessary parameters to adequately fit this model.
Heres the Code Block for the model:
input_shape=BUFFER_INPUT_SHAPE_WITHCHANNELS
# n_channels = input_shape[-1]
# encoder
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(256, (4,4), activation='relu', padding='same', 
input_shape=input_shape)) # (27086, 64, 1) 
model.add(MaxPool2D((2,2), padding='same'))
model.add(Conv2D(128, (4,4), activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(MaxPool2D((2,2), padding='same'))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (4,4), activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(MaxPool2D((2,2), padding="same"))
# decoder
model.add(Conv2D(64, (4,4), activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(UpSampling2D((2,2)))
model.add(Conv2D(128, (4,4), activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(UpSampling2D((2,2)))
model.add(Conv2D(256, (4,4), activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(UpSampling2D((2,2)))
model.add(Conv2D(1, (4,4), activation='sigmoid', 
padding='same'))

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_error', 
metrics=['mse'])
model.summary()
      



_________________________________________________________________

Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #
=

conv2d_135 (Conv2D)         (None, 27086, 64, 256)    4352

max_pooling2d_60 (MaxPoolin  (None, 13543, 32, 256)   0  
g2D)

conv2d_136 (Conv2D)         (None, 13543, 32, 128)    524416

max_pooling2d_61 (MaxPoolin  (None, 6772, 16, 128)    0  
g2D)

conv2d_137 (Conv2D)         (None, 6772, 16, 64)      131136

max_pooling2d_62 (MaxPoolin  (None, 3386, 8, 64)      0  
g2D)

conv2d_138 (Conv2D)         (None, 3386, 8, 64)       65600

up_sampling2d_58 (UpSamplin  (None, 6772, 16, 64)     0  
g2D)

conv2d_139 (Conv2D)         (None, 6772, 16, 128)     131200

up_sampling2d_59 (UpSamplin  (None, 13544, 32, 128)   0  
g2D)

conv2d_140 (Conv2D)         (None, 13544, 32, 256)    524544

up_sampling2d_60 (UpSamplin  (None, 27088, 64, 256)   0  
g2D)

conv2d_141 (Conv2D)         (None, 27088, 64, 1)      4097

If you see any other tipps or improvements, please let me know.
I tried to change the pooling, kernel and stride parameters. I also tried to change the original input by trimming it to a shape which will be divisible multiple times. However, im not sure whether this approach is usually done.
EDIT:
I trimmed the Data to the shape (27072,64,1). But this does not seem to be the appropriate way to deal with my issue. I didn't want to trim my data
